How can I reset my apple ID on all my devices synchronously?
I am running Sonoma 14.5 on a macBook Pro, Macbook Air M2, iOS 17.5.1 & mac Pro Monterey 12.7.5.  I am consistently be asked to change  my apple ID password.  How can I force change it synchronously on all devices if they are all powered up & online?  Thanks for any help....Pat O

You don't need to change it on all of them.  You need to change it on one of them.
The others will then get logged out of iCloud and will prompt for the new password.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/101567

If you use the web interface, Apple will push a notification to all devices and they will receive them as soon as they are online if not immediately for those currently online.
